# Configure dynamodb stream event source triggers to have configurable delay for retries

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, amazon-dynamodb-streams

We have basically

```
    dynamodb streams => 
      trigger lambda (batch size XX, concurrency 1, retries YY) => 
        write to service
```

There are multiple shards, so we may have some number of concurrent writes to the service.  Under some conditions too many streams have too much data, and too many lambda instances are writing to the service, which then responds with `429`.

Right now the failure simply ends up being a failure, the lambda retries, but the service is still overwhelmed.

What we would like to do is just have the lambda triggers delay before triggering a lambda retry, essentially have an exponential backoff before triggering.  We can easily implement that "inside" the lambda, we can retry and wait for up to the 15m lambda duration.

But then we are billed for whole lambda execution time, while it is sleeping for however many backoffs are required.

**Is there a way to configure the lambda/dynamodb trigger to have a delay (that we can control up and down) before invoking the retry?  For SQS triggers there is some talk of `redrive policy` that somehow can control the rate of retries - but not clear how or if that applies to dynamodb streams.**

I understand that the streams will "backup" as we slow down the dispatch of lambdas, but this is assumed to be a transient situation, and the dynamodb stream will act as a queue.  And we can also configure a dead letter queue, but that is sort of orthogonal to the basic question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with step functions, but added that tag - maybe it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can configure a wait. And yes, while you are billed by the time use, its pennies. Seriously, the free aws account covers a million lambda invocations a month. At the enterprise level its really nothing compared to what EC2 servers cost. But Im not your CFO so maybe it is a concern.
2. You can take your stream and process it into whatever service calls you would need and have their payloads all added to the same SQS. You can configure your SQS to throttle it self in effect, so it only sends so many over a given time. The messages in your queue wold go to another lambda that would do the service call for you, one at a time. It would be doled out by the SQS
3. set up a Dead Letter Queue instead (possibly in combination with either of the above) to catch the failed ones and try again when traffic is lower.

As an aside, you don't want to 'pause' your dynamo stream as it only has a 24 hour TTL on it. If your stream pauses for too long you will lose data. Better to take the stream in whole and put it into an SQS queue as individual writes because SQS has a TTL of up to 14 days.

Comment: Thanks, @lynkfox, can you show a link to docs to configuring a wait for a lambda triggered by a dynamodb stream?  I am planning to configure a DLQ

Comment: There isn't one. I meant a wait inside the lambda. You can set dynamo streams to have a minimum batch size (#of records) or minimum time (ie fire even if you haven't hit the batch every 5 mins). I suppose you could set a very high batch # and a set min wait... but not sure that would really work for your described use case

Comment: OK, I think I found a way -- the Batch Window size.  I think rn our batch size is generally not being reached, so increasing BatchWindow would act as a delay.    Anyways, thanks.  I was sort of hoping I could do something explicit, like delay retries specifically.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. It (and pretty much all aws) is designed as an on event style system that moves to have as little latency as possible. Because you're integrating with a non aws system that can't scale the same you have these problems.

Comment: I think you'd be better serviced by having a lambda take the stream and generate your  external service payloads, then put those payloads in an SQS. Those queues have settings for delay and wait between messages or batches of messages, plus dead letter queues yo catch the ones that fail. The SQS can send straight to your external  endpoint if you don't need anything other than a success/fail response - otherwise put another lambda